# Clock with varying time period System verilog

Tags: clock, clock-speed, system-verilog

I needed help in writing a test bench with a varying clock time period.
need to invoke the clock using a task in the test bench.

Comment: Use a programable counter.

Comment: You may need help, but what exactly is your question?

Comment: I was clear to me what the OP was asking - how to model a varying clock in a testbench.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a task to do this. All you need is an initial block using a variable for the period.

```
int Period=10ns;
int Offset=20ps;
bit Clock;
initial begin
    Clock = 0;
    #(Offset)
    forever #(Period/2) Clock = ! Clock;
   end

initial begin
   #100ms Period = 8ns;
   #100ms Period = 6ns;
end
```